# How to form sentence embeddings from word embeddings using glove on dataframe trained tensors?

Tags: python, machine-learning, word-embedding, glove

I am working with a dataset containing snippets of event information. My dataframe looks similar to:

```
index| event_description
----------------------
1    | concert with thousands of people
2    | people gathering 
3    | there was an event in the city and it was so much fun
...
8000 | very boring gathering
```

My job is to cluster these events based on their meanings. I do not know how many events there should be, that's the job of the unsupervised learning.

In order to proceed with the DBSCAN clustering I have embedded all words in my dataframe into vectors using GloVe (rather doc2Vec, etc).

How do you convert word vectors into sentence vectors, to proceed to clustering?

I have read this [article](https://medium.com/explorations-in-language-and-learning/how-to-obtain-sentence-vectors-2a6d88bd3c8b) as well as some other posts and papers, which use other sentence embedding algorithms, not GloVe word embedding. Also, some repos like [InferSent](https://github.com/facebookresearch/InferSent) and [Google universal sentence encoder](https://alpha.tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1) are pretty good, however they are using pre trained tensors.

Given these constraints, that I must use GloVe and dataframe trained tensors rather than pretrained ones, how can I form sentence vectors from word vectors?